# 70's live action Saturday morning time travel show

Tags: story-identification, time-travel

It was possibly interdimensional or alternate timeline travel not actual time travel

In one episode they traveled to a society that had assigned everyone numbers instead of names and they wore helmets with their number on it, so you couldn't see their face. 2 people had fallen in love and this was not allowed. I think the explanation was to keep people from judging people on their looks. This might have just been part of an episode and this was just the closing scene.

Possibly the same show - Robots are slaves to humans and gain freedom. Last scene woman with bright colored hair and spring shaped bun on top of head, allows robot to play with bun.

I'm pretty sure it was a US TV show and the actors were mostly teens/preteens.

I don't think it was "Ark II" but it had a similar look.

Comment: Welcome to SFF.SE! You've provided a fair amount of information, but you still may want to look at the answers to [this question](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9335/) to see if these additional ideas make you think of anything else that might help. Any recollection of what channel it was on? You think it was a US show - were you watching it in the US? Can you narrow down the timeframe at all (early vs late 70s; a specific year is even better, of course)?

Comment: That first described episode sounds like one form "Buck Rogers" Series 2. The reason in that for the helmets was the lack of genetic diversity - All the males were identical in appearance, as were all the females, due to an accident in longevity research. But I think "Buck" was primetime.

Comment: Kind of reminds me of *Josh Kirby... Time Warrior!* (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Josh_Kirby..._Time_Warrior!), but that was the 90s.

Answer (score 2):

This is a long shot as your details are a little thin,  but it could be the serial called the Fantastic Journey. It featured characters lost in the Bermuda Triangle being transported to different times and alien worlds which would fit your mention of "possibly inter dimensional or alternate time lines" It aired in the late 1970's so fits your time scale. I only vaguely remember episode details but do recall an episode with robots.

Check out this wikipedia link for details
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Fantastic_Journey

here is a youtube link to an episode that apparently features robots, although its actually not what I recall, which just goes to show how fuzzy memory gets over time.